# How to retrieve parameters from response body

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, spotify

I am trying to set up Spotify authorization using Authorization Code Flow ( as from https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow ) and got stuck receiving the tokens from the Spotify server.

When I make the POST request, I log the response body and set two variables: access and refresh tokens. The response body indeed contains these tokens, the variables are, however, are `undefined` (see logs).

```
console.log("Response.body: ")
console.log(response.body);

var access_token = response.body['access_token'],
    refresh_token = response.body['refresh_token'];
console.log("Access: " + access_token);
console.log("Refresh: " + refresh_token);
```

I've tried both `body.access_token` and `response.body.access_token` as well.

```
A 2019-09-03T09:13:03.184411Z Response.body:  
A 2019-09-03T09:13:03.184575Z {"scope":"playlist-modify-private","access_token":"BQAjB5eurOdl3oM2j-8db4pKi-...","token_type":"Bearer","refresh_token":"AQDtEcfw… 
A 2019-09-03T09:13:03.184607Z Access: undefined 
A 2019-09-03T09:13:03.184618Z Refresh: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to convert the body to a proper object before trying to access properties.
Try the following:

```
const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
```

Comment: Bravo! Kudos to you.